# How to get a list of components that were imported in <script setup>?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-script-setup

Is there any way to get the list of components that were imported in `<script setup>` ?

I need this to dynamically create a mapper to convert strings of the component names to the components themselves , something like this :

```
<template>
    <component
      v-for="(module, key, index) in modules"
      :key="`module_${key}_${index}`"
      :is="get_component(module.componentname)"
    />
</template>    

<script setup>
import moduletypeA from "components/componentA.vue";
import moduletypeB from "components/componentB.vue";

const modules = [
  { modulename: "A1", componentname: "moduletypeA" },
  { modulename: "A2", componentname: "moduletypeA" },
  { modulename: "B1", componentname: "moduletypeB" },
  { modulename: "B2", componentname: "moduletypeB" },
]

const components = [
  { componentname: "moduletypeA", component: moduletypeA},
  { componentname: "moduletypeB", component: moduletypeB},
];

function get_component(name) {
  let component = components.find((obj) => {
    return obj.componentname === componentname;
  });
  return component.component;
}
</script>
```

This works, because of the corresponding `components` array with each imported component and a string to find them, but I would like to make this more generic, based on the imports.

Basically the definition of the `components` array should be made automatically from the components that were imported, but how do I get these?

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this might be usefull, but I guess you can access the components name (if set). Like:

```
<template>
    <component
      v-for="(component, index) in components"
      :key="`module_${component.name}_${index}`"
      :is="component"
    />
</template>    

<script setup>
import compA from "components/componentA.vue";
import compB from "components/componentB.vue";

const components = [
  compA,
  compB
]
</script>
```

[DEMO:](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

[DEMO (updated)](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Interesting idea, and a bit simpler than my solution, but it doesn't work. since `component.name` is undefined

Comment: Thanks. This way of setting the name in a separate script tag is really ugly though :)

Comment: And this works only if you import the component with the same name as defined in the component. I like to be able to only know the filename of the component, but use the tagname that I choose (compA while the component's name and filename is componentA)...

Comment: Thats not true. You can pass the whole component to `<component />` if you use `:is`.
I've updated my demo